# Можно ли повторно считать символ из порта 60h? Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, прерывания

Пишу свой обработчик прерывания 09h. Необходимо эмулировать нажатие клавиш Shift, Tab, Backspace используя NumPad1, NumPad2, NumPad3 соответственно. Возник вопрос: если я считаю один раз scan-code из порта 60h, а потом передам управление системному обработчику, он корректно отработает? То есть после чтения символа из порта 60h я смогу его считать оттуда еще раз или в порте уже этого символа не будет? Заранее благодарю!

PS: Пишу в среде DOS, поэтому доступ к портам имеется

Comment: Байт из 60h можно читать повторно любое количество раз - он там будет лежать до тех пор, пока ты не зашлёшь подтверждение в порт 61h.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы даже не представляете, на сколько помогли) Очень спасибо)